# Stop jquery each loop

Tags: jquery

How can i stop $.each loop?

```
$.each(files, function(index, file){
    if(file.field_index == remove_file_index){
        //Find remove_file_index Stop $.each
    }
});

Continue to execute code...
```

Thanks

Comment: `return false;` will stop the loop, `break` statment. `return true;` or `return;` will act as `continue` statement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `return false` to stop the loop

Comment: hmm why not just `return;`?

Comment: @Johny `return;` is equal to continue statement, that's why

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle demonstrating breaking out of the loop:
http://jsfiddle.net/9XqRy/

```
// Array
var bar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// Generic function
function loopTest(exit) {
    // jQuery each
    $.each(bar, function (i, o) {
        // Append result to foo div
        $("#foo").append(o + "<br />");
        // If exit is passed, and i is 4, return false
        if (exit && i == 4) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

// Without exit
loopTest();

// Create a seperator for visual
 $("#foo").append("<br />---<br /><br />");

// With exit
loopTest(true);
```